# How to display the target whose recipe is not executed

Tags: makefile

I am invoking a makefile:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : %.c  
<PRE> @$(CC) $@ -o $< </PRE>
```

If we have 100 source files and 50 objects are already exist.
While invoking make , it will execute recipe for 51st object file.

If I want output something like this:

```
<br>
Obj1.c skipped...<br>
Obj2.c skipped...<br>
.<br>
Compiling Obj51.c...<br>
```

What we should write for that ?

Answer (score 0):

Some make utilities have special debugging mode for track more actions. E.g., with GNU make files, which are not rebuilt, can be tracked with `--debug=v` option:

```
make --debug=v
```

Description of this option in [GNU make documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Options-Summary):

> A level above ‘basic’; includes messages about which makefiles were parsed, prerequisites that did not need to be rebuilt, etc. This option also enables ‘basic’ messages.

Comment: Thanks for answer.But it thrown lot of information that I don't want to print. <br> There is no other way ?